# Using Google Sign-in for Internal Web App

Tags: javascript, google-signin, google-identity

I am trying to use Google Sign-in Web API to enable users to log in to an internal network web app. The app will never be hosted publicly.

I have it working all well and fine from http://localhost but when users then access the web app over the network (Via IP i.e. http://10.24.122.34/) the Google Sign-in gives me a 400 Error: invalid_request.

I have the IP address set as an Authorised Javascript origin but I still get the 400 error

Is there a way to allow Google Sign-in to work over local network?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project add you url to Authorized JavaScript origins

Comment: @SilentTremor that is the problem. I have the IP address set as an Authorised Javascript origin but I still get the 400 error

Comment: Port is present there? even default one :80

Comment: @SilentTremor yeah I've tried with and without the port number. No such luck :(

Comment: Hi man, I've tested on my local (IP) for an existing project, dude it's true, not working, sorry I don't tested what I've suggested.